# Spring Data JPA: query ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have entities `User` and `Test`

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String userName;
}

@Entity
public class Test {
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

I can get all tests by User entity:

```
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<EventSettings, Long> {
    List<Test> findAllByUsers(User user);
}
```

But which query can I use for finding all tests by `userName`?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The following method signature will get you want to want:

```
List<Test> findByUsers_UserName(String userName)
```

This is using the [property expression](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) feature of Spring Data JPA. The signature `Users_UserName` will be translated to the JPQL `x.users.userName`. Note that this will perform an exact match on the given username.

Comment: how to make this in JPQL (in Query annotation)?

Comment: it can be achieved using join. see my answer.

Answer (score 15):

I was using @JoinTable and I got it working with this :

```
@Query("select t from Test t join t.users u where u.username = :username")
List<Test> findAllByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
```

`t.users u` instead of `User u`

Answer (score 12):

Other answer shows how to achieve desired functionality using function naming technique. We can achieve same functionality using @Query annotation as follows:

```
@Query("select t from Test t join User u where u.username = :username")
List<Test> findAllByUsername(@Param("username")String username);
```

Comment: But why though?

Comment: @KevinVanDyck - Because you need to put the condition on the User entity but the many-to-many is not defined as bidirectional so you have to start off from the entity that defines it, ie. Test

Answer (score 1):

You can use without underscore too

```
List<Test> findByUsersUserName(String userName)
```