# Spring JPA Query: Third table

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have three tables: user, home, user_home.

In code i have entity User and Home.

In repository i want to get users by home address.

I`m using next code:

```
@Query("select u " +
        "from UserHome m " +
        "join User u on m.user_id = u.user_id " +
        "join Home h on m.home_id = h.home_id " +
        "where h.address = :address")
List<Users> findByHomeAddress(@Param("address") String address);
```

But i receive next message:"QuerySyntaxException: UserHome is not mapped"

Comment: Most likely there's an issue in the code of your entities where you should have implemented  @ManyToMany mapping, and this important part is missing.

Comment: You may want to review this answer explaining [how create a query for ManyToMany relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438483/spring-data-jpa-query-manytomany)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table name which you are using in the query should match exactly the *entity* name as you are writing the custom query. Check once.